# Tell everyone out there

Tags: meaning

Assume a reporter is talking to the best player of just completed basketball game and ask him in the following manner:

> Tell everyone ***out there*** what it feels like to be the next Lebron
>   James.

Why did he use out there? Why would not say just tell everyone, without "**out there**". Is the point going to be changed in that case or what?

What I did first to understand that was looking for the phrasal verb ***tell sb out***. Since I didn't find anything similar I decided to look for `out there` and found the following referece: [clatz](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/out+there). Unfortunately it wasn't helpful too.

Maybe you can clarify that point?

It's also not clear where I'm supposed to use ***out there*** and where ***over there***

Comment: You can take it like this: *Tell everyone [who is] out there...*

Comment: 'everyone out there' = the audience, local or on radio/TV. It's become an over-used reporterism.

Comment: As Tetsujin said. Variant: *everyone out there in TV-land*. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+out+there+in+TV+land&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20there%20in%20TV%20land%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano So the differnce between out there and over there is what? Out there is used inly for TV-reportism, huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"out there" is farther and/or more indeterminate (uncertain) than "over there" (*over there* is ostensive, i.e. pointing in a particular direction)

"Everybody out there [in TV-land"]  comprises a dispersed mass of people that the announcer cannot see—he has no idea how many they are, nor how widely they are dispersed; so they are not just "over there", they are everywhere (all around), near and far, but out of sight to the announcer. In other words, **out there**.

As to whether this applies only to TV announcers—no, a similar reasoning applies to, for instance, the search for intelligence in the rest of the universe:

- "Is there anybody **out there?**.

  Or to a more down-to -earth situation such as a mom standing at her back door, after dark, and yelling:
- "Hey, kids, are you **out there?**"

  She thinks they might be "out" in the back yard, and located at an indefinite "somewhere" but she cannot see them.